# How to correctly use coercions such that no parenthesis are needed?

Tags: bnfc

Why does the following grammar does not recognize `nat -> nat` but does recognize `(nat -> nat)` and how can I fix that?

```
 TNat . Typ4 ::= "nat" ;                                                        
 TVoid . Typ4 ::= "<>" ;    
 TProd . Typ3 ::= SumType;                                
 TProd . Typ2 ::= Typ2 "*" Typ3;                                                
 TArrow . Typ1 ::= Typ1 "->" Typ2;                                              
 coercions Typ 4;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inverting the order of declaration fixed the issue

```
TArrow . Typ ::= Typ "->" Typ1;
TSum . Typ1 ::= SumType;
TProd . Typ2 ::= Typ2 "*" Typ3;
TNat . Typ3 ::= "nat" ;
TVoid . Typ3 ::= "<>" ;
coercions Typ 3;
```

Comment: I'm happy to see that you found a solution. To give a bit of explanation: unless you [set it explicitly](http://bnfc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lbnf.html#entry-point-pragmas), the entry point of your grammar is going to be the category of the first rule. An alternative would have been to add `entrypoints Typ ;` to set the entry point.